# Error al validar ticket en servidor CAS

Tags: java, servidor

Estoy tratando de montar un CAS (servidor central de autentificacion)
En el xml de la aplicación pongo algo asi:

```
<!-- Filter to handle logout requests sent directly by the CAS server -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8443/cas/logout</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/ConsentimientosInformados/m/logout</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- Listener to clean sessions -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Define the protected urls of your application -->
    <!-- #### change with your own CAS server and your host name #### -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>casServerLoginUrl</param-name>
            <param-value>https://localhost:8443/cas/login</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>serverName</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8080/ConsentimientosInformados</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Define the urls on which you can validate a service ticket -->
    <!-- #### change with your own CAS server and your host name #### -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8443/cas</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>serverName</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8080/ConsentimientosInformados</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Put the CAS principal in the HTTP request -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS HttpServletRequest Wrapper Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

La redirección la ace correctamente, me autentifico, crea un ticket, pero al validar (pienso yo), salta un error.
Pongo la traza de error que salta:

```
GRAVE: Unexpected end of file from server
java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:429)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:41)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:193)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

may 05, 2017 1:26:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() para servlet jsp lanzó excepción
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:443)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:41)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:193)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.authentication.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:429)
    ... 24 more
```

¿A que se puede deber?
¿Estoy definiendo algo mal?
Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltaba un filtro para controlar el cierre de sesion que pondre al final por si alguien lo necesita

Y para soluconar el error, revisa la creación y exportacion de un certificado para la web, en mi caso fue eso, al rehacerlo y asegurandome que el nombre y apellidos del certificado era localhost para las pruebas en local que estoy haciendo.

Filtro para cerrar sesion:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
            <param-value>https://localhost:8443/cas</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```